# SQL set different variables in single SELECT from same column and table, different conditions

Tags: sql-server

I have a the basics of SQL down. But I might need some advanced help with this problem.

I'm developing an API that executes different SQL prepared statements, now I'm trying to optimise these queries.

Currently my one prepared statement has multiple select statements that selects from the same table, but each has their own conditions, for example:

```
DECLARE 
  @DESCRIPTION_1 NVARCHAR(200)
, @DESCRIPTION_2 NVARCHAR(200)
, @DESCRIPTION_3 NVARCHAR(200)

SELECT @DESCRIPTION_1 = [DESCRIPTION] FROM [Objectives] WHERE [OBJECTIVE_ID] = '4E2DEA7B-025A-4958-8696-2D13EDD3E08E';
SELECT @DESCRIPTION_2 = [DESCRIPTION] FROM [Objectives] WHERE [OBJECTIVE_ID] = '81B9B7E5-A833-4C5A-9B73-CBACFB055404';
SELECT @DESCRIPTION_3 = [DESCRIPTION] FROM [Objectives] WHERE [OBJECTIVE_ID] = 'A065CF91-01C9-41A8-A326-A00402329833';
```

*This is only a condensed version of my query. The original looks like this:

```
SELECT 
  @OBJECTIVE_1_DESCRIPTION = [dbo].[Objectives].[OBJECTIVE_DESCRIPTION]
, @OBJ1_LVL = [dbo].[Objectives].[OBJECTIVE_LEVEL]
, @OBJ1_TARGET = [dbo].[Objectives].[OBJECTIVE_COMPETION_COUNT]
, @REWARD_1_CODE = [dbo].[Objectives].[OBJECTIVE_REWARD]
FROM [dbo].[Objectives] 
WHERE [dbo].[Objectives].[OBJECTIVE_ID] = @OBJECTIVE1_ID;
```

Is there any way I can combine this into a single SELECT statement?

Comment: Why not a `SELECT ... WHERE OBJECTIVE_ID IN ...`?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, that would only let all 3 DESCRIPTIONS have the same value. Each one needs to have a unique value.

Comment: You'd get 3 rows each one with a single value. You could store that in a table-valued field, although it would be faster to use a query to get the final result, instead of storing intermediate results in a variable

Comment: Is this question solved? Do you need further help? Please allow me one hint: It would be very kind of you to tick the acceptance check below the best answer's vote counter. This will 1) mark this issue as solved 2) make it easier for followers to find the best solution 3) pay points to the answerer and 4) pay points to you. Once you crossed the 15 points border yourself you are - additionally - asked to vote on contributions. This is the SO-way to say thank you. Happy Coding!

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE 
  @DESCRIPTION_1 NVARCHAR(200)
, @DESCRIPTION_2 NVARCHAR(200)
, @DESCRIPTION_3 NVARCHAR(200)

Select @DESCRIPTION_1 = max(case when [OBJECTIVE_ID] = '4E2DEA7B-025A-4958-8696-2D13EDD3E08E' then [DESCRIPTION] else null end) 
      ,@DESCRIPTION_2 = max(case when [OBJECTIVE_ID] = '81B9B7E5-A833-4C5A-9B73-CBACFB055404' then [DESCRIPTION] else null end)      
      ,@DESCRIPTION_3 = max(case when [OBJECTIVE_ID] = 'A065CF91-01C9-41A8-A326-A00402329833' then [DESCRIPTION] else null end)      
FROM [Objectives]
Where [OBJECTIVE_ID] in ('4E2DEA7B-025A-4958-8696-2D13EDD3E08E','81B9B7E5-A833-4C5A-9B73-CBACFB055404','A065CF91-01C9-41A8-A326-A00402329833')
```

I would also declare 3 @OBJECTIVE_ID's to reduce the text and redundancy

Also the WHERE is optional, if you have a small table, remove it

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. This is only a condensed version of my query. The original one sets 8 variables in each select statement and each ID is assigned to a @OBJECTIVE_ID.

Comment: This isn't just a condensed version. The query in the question executes 3 different queries against the database. This is a single query.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos That's what I thought, but apparently DévanCoetzee didn't see it that way

Answer (score 0):

Why not set them immediately with a sub-select?

```
DECLARE @DESCRIPTION_1 NVARCHAR(200)=(SELECT [DESCRIPTION] FROM [Objectives] WHERE [OBJECTIVE_ID] = '4E2DEA7B-025A-4958-8696-2D13EDD3E08E');
DECLARE @DESCRIPTION_2 NVARCHAR(200)=(SELECT [DESCRIPTION] FROM [Objectives] WHERE [OBJECTIVE_ID] = '81B9B7E5-A833-4C5A-9B73-CBACFB055404');
DECLARE @DESCRIPTION_3 NVARCHAR(200)=(SELECT [DESCRIPTION] FROM [Objectives] WHERE [OBJECTIVE_ID] = 'A065CF91-01C9-41A8-A326-A00402329833');
```

Assuming there is an index on your `OBJECTIVE_ID` this should be very fast as well...

Comment: There are 18 variables I'm setting in 3 SELECT statements, I want to reduce the amount of SELECT statements.

Comment: @DévanCoetzee With an index each sub-select is lightning fast. I'd rather question the whole approach: *Why do you store these values in variables?* Any other solution will - most likely - take the same time or even more... You will - at least - need one select for each value in your `WHERE`. If this is your current approach this should be fine!

Comment: I insert these variables into a different table and return them. Thank you the advice, I really appreciate it. I'm trying to squeeze out every bit of efficiency I can.

Comment: @DévanCoetzee If you really try *to squeeze every bit of efficiency* I'm quite sure, there's a better approach... To avoid chameleon questions I'd suggest the following: This question is *SQL set different variables in single SELECT from same column and table, different conditions*. Please vote on all contributions which are helpfull (or bad) and - additionally! - pick out the best answer (up to you!) which solved **this** question. Then start a new question. Give some more details, Show what you are doing and what you want, and place a link to this question. Thx

Answer (score 0):

OK, one more shot if I may.   As you know, SQL Server does not support arrays, or dynamically create variables (sans dynamic SQL)

I should add, the IDENTITY keeps the appropriate order just in case it is important.

```
Declare @KeyID Table (Key_PS int identity,Key_Value varchar(100))
Insert Into @KeyID values (@OBJECTIVE1_ID),(@OBJECTIVE2_ID),(@OBJECTIVE3_ID)

SELECT @OBJECTIVE_1_DESCRIPTION  = max(IIF(Key_PS=1 ,[OBJECTIVE_DESCRIPTION],null))
     , @OBJ1_LVL                 = max(IIF(Key_PS=1 ,[OBJECTIVE_LEVEL],null))
     , @OBJ1_TARGET              = max(IIF(Key_PS=1 ,[OBJECTIVE_COMPETION_COUNT],null))
     , @REWARD_1_CODE            = max(IIF(Key_PS=1 ,[OBJECTIVE_REWARD],null)) 
     --... [2 - 17] ... --
     , @OBJECTIVE_18_DESCRIPTION = max(IIF(Key_PS=18,[OBJECTIVE_DESCRIPTION],null))
     , @OBJ18_LVL                = max(IIF(Key_PS=18,[OBJECTIVE_LEVEL],null))
     , @OBJ18_TARGET             = max(IIF(Key_PS=18,[OBJECTIVE_COMPETION_COUNT],null))
     , @REWARD_18_CODE           = max(IIF(Key_PS=18,[OBJECTIVE_REWARD],null)) 
FROM (Select B.*,A.* 
       From  [dbo].[Objectives] 
       Join  @KeyID B on (A.OBJECTIVE_ID=B.Key_Value)
     ) A
```

Answer (score -1):

Use UNION:

```
SELECT 
  @Objective1_Id Objective_Id,
  @OBJECTIVE_1_DESCRIPTION = [dbo].[Objectives].[OBJECTIVE_DESCRIPTION]
, @OBJ1_LVL = [dbo].[Objectives].[OBJECTIVE_LEVEL]
, @OBJ1_TARGET = [dbo].[Objectives].[OBJECTIVE_COMPETION_COUNT]
, @REWARD_1_CODE = [dbo].[Objectives].[OBJECTIVE_REWARD]
FROM [dbo].[Objectives] 
WHERE [dbo].[Objectives].[OBJECTIVE_ID] = @OBJECTIVE1_ID
UNION
SELECT 
  @Objective2_Id,
  @OBJECTIVE_1_DESCRIPTION = [dbo].[Objectives].[OBJECTIVE_DESCRIPTION]
, @OBJ1_LVL = [dbo].[Objectives].[OBJECTIVE_LEVEL]
, @OBJ1_TARGET = [dbo].[Objectives].[OBJECTIVE_COMPETION_COUNT]
, @REWARD_1_CODE = [dbo].[Objectives].[OBJECTIVE_REWARD]
FROM [dbo].[Objectives] 
WHERE [dbo].[Objectives].[OBJECTIVE_ID] = @OBJECTIVE2_ID
UNION
SELECT 
  @Objective3_Id,
  @OBJECTIVE_1_DESCRIPTION = [dbo].[Objectives].[OBJECTIVE_DESCRIPTION]
, @OBJ1_LVL = [dbo].[Objectives].[OBJECTIVE_LEVEL]
, @OBJ1_TARGET = [dbo].[Objectives].[OBJECTIVE_COMPETION_COUNT]
, @REWARD_1_CODE = [dbo].[Objectives].[OBJECTIVE_REWARD]
FROM [dbo].[Objectives] 
WHERE [dbo].[Objectives].[OBJECTIVE_ID] = @OBJECTIVE3_ID;
```

Assuming that rows exist for all @ObjectiveX_id, you have one query which will return 3 rows, each row containing the objective_id it relates to.

Comment: Since I don't have his tables, no I didn't. Why won't it work?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the actual data... just syntax. Try this `DECLARE @v1 INT,@v2 INT; SELECT @v1=1; /*UNION ALL*/ SELECT @v2=2; SELECT @v1,@v2;` And then take away the `;` and un-comment the `UNION ALL`... Btw: If it worked, it would write the values into the same variables (all with 1)... And Btw2: What would be the advantage of the same as three separate statements?

Comment: @simonatrcl: this query will generate this error: 
Variable assignment is not allowed in a statement containing a top level UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator.